# Xcode 13.1 with MacOS 12.0.1 cannot create iPhone 5s simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I get to here by clicking on the simulator drop-down at the top, clicking Add Additional Simulators, going to the simulators tab, and clicking the plus in the bottom left corner.

[image]

But if I click create, this happens. [image]

If I try to download an old runtime like iOS 11.4, it does not show up in the OS Version list like it used to. Does anybody know if something has changed since Xcode 12.5.1 and MacOS 11? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The latest version that runs on the 5S seems to be iOS 12, have you tried using that one?

Comment: Yes, I also tried 12, but again, it does not show up in the list after having been installed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the command `xcrun simctl list runtimes` in Teerminal you will see an output similar to this:

```
== Runtimes ==
iOS 11.4 (11.4 - 15F79) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4 (unavailable, The iOS 11.4 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 11.99.0.)
iOS 12.0 (12.0 - 16A366) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0 (unavailable, The iOS 12.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 11.99.0.)
iOS 15.2 (15.2 - 19C51) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2
tvOS 15.2 (15.2 - 19K50) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-15-2
watchOS 8.3 (8.3 - 19S51) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-8-3
```

Your output may be different depending on the simulators you have installed on your system.

As it appears, some versions of iOS are not compatible with macOS 12+.

Even if you try to do it from Terminal, as such:

`xcrun simctl create 'iPhone 5s (12.0)' com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0`

You will get an error like:

```
Unable to create a device for device type: iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s), runtime: iOS 12.0 (12.0 - 16A366) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0 (unavailable, The iOS 12.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 11.99.0.)
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=401):
The iOS 12.0 simulator runtime is not available.
The iOS 12.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 11.99.0.
The iOS 12.0 simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 12.0.1
```

I have yet to find a list of which iOS simulators are compatible, nor a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, `xcrun simctl list runtimes` was perfect to find out ios12 not compatible with macOS Ventura